# Add change listener on data attributes for multiple elements

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, dom

Say that JS renders a few input fields, that all have different id's as the `data-id` value. How do I add event listeners to all inputs that have the `data-id` attribute, and then send it to PHP as an AJAX request?

```js
<input type="text" data-id="${element.id}" class="review" name="review" placeholder="Type your review"/>
```

```js
xmlHttp.open("GET", "/review=" + << input field value here >>, true);
```

Answer (score 1):

You did not specify which event you want to listen for. I assumed a "change" event, but you could modify it to whatever you choose.

You can select elements by an attribute name using `querySelectorAll` and putting the name of the attribute in square brackets.

```
const els = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('[data-id]'));
for(const el of els) {
  el.addEventListener('change', () => {
    //your ajax code here
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use document.querySelectorAll('input[data-id]') for fetching all input elements having "data-id" as attribute and then loop over the HTML elements and add eventlistener to each of it as follows:

```
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('input[data-id]');
elements.forEach(key => {
      key.addEventListener('change', console.log('Event added!!!'));
});
```

In case you want to add event to input element have a particular data-id value you can use the following format to get just one element:

```
const id=1;
const specificInput = document.querySelector(`input[data-key="${id}"]`);
```